# android sqllite cannot be accessed from outside package

Tags: android, sqlite

I am making an Android app to learn sqllite. Because I use 7 tables, I decided to create 7 class files in a folder "DBHelper", and want to make 7 files in a folder "DBadapter". Here what the structure looks like:

root

- DBHelper: 7 helper files (ex: PersonHelper.java)
- DBadapter: 7 adapter files (ex: PersonDAO.java)

But I get an error message with PersonDAO.java: "cannot be accessed from outside package", when I declared the object: "PersonHelper personHelper = new PersonHelper(context);" in the constructor.

Anyone has an idea how to fix that without putting all files in one folder? What is the standard in the industry when creating multiple large tables?

PS: The error is gone once I place all files in one directory.

```
public class PersonDAO {
private Context context;

//Database info
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDB";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

//Table helper info
public PersonHelper databaseHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db = null;


//Constructors
PersonDAO(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    databaseHelper = new PersonHelper(context); //Error: "cannot be accessed from outside package"
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code of personHelper or at least the constructor there?

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor of your `PersonHelper` is probably default like it is in your PersonDAO class. So it can only be accessed from the same package. You have to change it to public to access it from PersonDAO:

```
public PersonHelper(Context context){
   ...
}
```